# list_empty function of linux kernel return value

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I am trying to write a scheduler. As a part of which I am using the function 
list_empty() to check whether it returns NULL or non zero value.

If i use it as,

```
 if(!list_empty(<I fill in the head pointer here>)) {
   <do necessary operations>
return 1;
}
return 0;
```

my kernel does not crash. 
But if I implement the same logic as,

```
 if(list_empty(<I fill in the head pointer here>)) {
return 0;
}
<do necessary operations>
return 1;
```

my Kernel blows up. I can get my code working by implementing it the first way but not the second. I just want to know the reason behind this difference in behavior. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Probably insufficient information.  Possibly some *side-effect* of `list_empty`, that differs between returning null and not null that affects the subsequent execution.  You probably need to post the actual code, and the implementation of `list_empty` - it is elided to far. Note that NULL is a pointer value; if `empty_list` does not return a pointer, you should return zero.

Comment: it is not possible to tell without posting the exact code (list_empty(<I fill in the head pointer here>)). "list_empty" just compares pointers. it crashes only if you pass "head" as NULL.